# how do I return two data types within a function that takes in a different data type then what needs to get returned?

Tags: c, function

i have a char that I want to pass up to a function and work on it then pass back two ints. something like this.

ADDED: looks like some are getting a little confused. I am just passing a char and needing to return 2 integers. the block of code works I just want to make it into a function to call it. it scripts off the two sides 100x200 - takes them the 100 and 200 then recast them into integers then returns them ..... this is what that functions needs to do, not pass in integers then return them.

```
 int func(char *whereisX)
{
char *tok1, *tok2, *saveptr;

tok1 = strtok_r(whereisX, "x", &saveptr);
tok2 = strtok_r(NULL, "x", &saveptr);


W = atoi(tok1); // now an integer
H = atoi(tok2); // now an integer

  return W; // w in returned -- BUT H is left wondering how to get back to main 
} 



int main( int argc, **argv)
 {

    strcpy (str1, argv[i]);



    int width = func(str1); // W gets returned

    int height = func(str1); H does not that call part is bad code it will not work

 ..........
```

it needs to now return two integers and not a char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a pointers to the output integers in the function arguments.

```
void someFunction(char *input, int *output_1, int *output_2)
{
    int result_1, result_2;

    // ... some process on *input to get result_1 and result_2

    /* assigning the results to the output */
    *output_1 = result_1;
    *output_2 = result_2;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo (int *a, int *b) {
// Dereference a pointer to assign a value.
    *a = 666;
    *b = 667;
}

int main (void) {
    int one, two;
// Use the address of operator to create pointers.
    foo(&one, &two);
    printf("%d %d\n", one, two);
    return 0;
}
```

By passing a pointer to the `int`s to `foo()`, the value assigned to them in `foo()` is retained in `main()`.

Comment: That or returning a struct can be useful too.

Comment: I am passing a one char into the function and returning two  int's - back or want to. I just thought because I know what I am looking for that I could return one as an int in the return of that function then pass the other back through the pram as &char then recast it as an Int in main.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @goldilocks is good, or alternatively:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct two_ints {
  int a, b;
};

struct two_ints get_my_answer(char c) {
  struct two_ints ans;

  // ... do something with c, or whatever

  ans.a = 3;
  ans.b = 7;
  return ans;
}

int main() {
  struct two_ints foo;
  foo = get_my_answer('x');
  printf("%d %d\n", foo.a, foo.b);
  return 0;
}
```